# JavaScript calculates image dimensions different from Firefox (?)

Tags: javascript, image, firefox, height, width

I have a resized image on a web page. The height returned by javascript line:

```
alert(document.getElementById("myimg").height);
```

or

```
alert(document.getElementById("myimg").clientHeight);
```

is different from the (correct) one returned by Firefox (right click -> view image info). The same for width.
How can I force JavaScript to calculate image dimensions as Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/naturalHeight

```
element.naturalWidth
element.naturalHeight
```

Comment: I did not explain myself well. I do not want the image original size. I point out that there is a difference of some pixels between the resized image dimensions reported by Firefox and the ones returned by JavaScript. For example, I have a resized image which according to Firefox is 536x321 (copy and paste in Paint.net confirms this) while accordiing to JavaScript is 552x330.

Comment: Could you share html and css on http://jsfiddle.net/ (or similar site) that reproduces the results you get?